# What is the basic setting needed to make GWT work with Errai bus

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
RequestURI=/index.jsp

Powered by jetty://
```

When adding this to the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErraiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.errai.bus.server.servlet.DefaultBlockingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErraiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.erraiBus</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>errai.properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/errai.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When this setting is removed, my Errai gwt application works fine, except that it shows Errai bus error on the client, however I need to make Errai bus work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish this helps you

[video-gwt-and-errai-ui-quickstart](http://ocpsoft.org/jboss/video-gwt-and-errai-ui-quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

You can download Jboss forge (works like spring roo) and use the errai plugin, or you can use maven, and build a basic errai project through an errai archetype.